# Convert web response from JSON to XML

Tags: xml, web-services

I created in asmx logic i get return data in json but i need to convert to xml  format below the if condition code logic

```
 if (providers[1] == Portal.*****.ToString())
    {
    CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();
    var Session = obj1.GetRequest(cookie);
    var MmtHotelid = obj1.Login("**********", "******", ref hotelid,cookie);
    var ListGetRoomtype = obj1.GetRoomTypes(MmtHotelid, Session);
    var list1 = obj1.GetRoomAvail(MmtHotelid, fromdate, todate, ListGetRoomtype, Session);
    listgetinv.InvetorYDetails.Add(list1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

var CtRateXml = new XElement("Provider", new XAttribute("Id", Portal.*****`enter code here`), from c in listgetinv
                                                                                             select new XElement("RoomType", new XAttribute("Name", c.RoomName),
                                                                                                from od in c.cleartriprate
                                                                                                select new XElement("Rate",
                                                                                                    new XElement("Date", od.Date),
                                                                                                    new XElement("SingleRate", od.SingleSellRate),
                                                                                                    new XElement("DoubleRate", od.DoubleSellRate)
                                                                                                    )));